# Preventing user to click on a particular button when an action is being performed

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008

Here's the scenario:
Platform: Windows
IDE: Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Language: C#
.NET framework: 3.5

My application contains 2 `buttons` - "Load Data" and "Stop Loading Data" and a `multi-line textbox`. Upon clicking "Load Data" `button` some data starts getting loaded in the `textbox`. To prevent the user clicking on the "Load Data" `button` multiple times, I have disabled that `button` once it is clicked. When the entire data gets loaded in the `textbox` then the "Load Data" `button` gets activated again. On the other hand on clicking "Stop Loading Data" `button` the loading of data is stopped (if user wishes to stop it before loading the entire content).
As stated earlier, to prevent the user clicking on the "Load Data" `button` multiple times, I have disabled that `button` with the intention that user can only click on "Stop Loading Data" `button` or else wait for the entire data to be loaded in the `textbox`. I implemented this. At first glance it seemed to work well. But while testing I found that even though the "Load Data" `button` is disabled, if the user clicks on that `button`, although nothing happens at that instant but as soon as the entire data gets loaded and the `button` becomes enabled again, that click made during the disabled state is found to be executed. As if the program was recording the keystrokes and mouse clicks and waiting for the button to become active again. But there are no such keystrokes or mouse-clicks recording facility in my program. What is causing such an activity? How can I prevent such behavior?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you blocking the UI by not using a background thread to perform the operation?

Comment: @winSharp93: I am using a background thread for carrying out the operation. But still I was having some problem. Thanks to Yahia, as the suggested solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to work with a reentrancy sentinel:

You could define an `int` field (initialize with 0) and update it via [`Interlocked.Increment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) on entering the method and only proceed if it is 1. At the end just do a [`Interlocked.Decrement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z4b2e5y.aspx).

To make it visible for the user you can disable the button at the beginning of execution and enable it when the execution is finished...

BTW: long-running tasks should be done async (via a separate thread for example)...

Comment: Id really go for this solution. Plus, you can use this technique in your business also :).

Comment: yeah, that why I use it often in my business. Its the pretty much the same mechanic when you start a job in a thread, and dont want to launch another job before the first one has finished.

Comment: Imo, this is a overengineered silution.

Comment: @Tigran I agree that for certain situations there might be simpler solutions... but basically I like to stick to patterns which work for a broad range of situations

Answer (score 0):

if you make your call a synchronous one, it will lock up the entire page until loading finishes.

Otherwise you'd be just doing the method you've already tried, i'd like to see your code for the disabled state, because something tells me you just made it appear to be disabled, and it was still a functional button

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post:

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=480279

My first thought was removing the event handler and rebinding it at the end of the click event. This thread suggests using a BackgroundWorker and making it async.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that you can't even move the form until data is loaded, and you also can't stop loading data. The problem is that the whole form freezes until loading is done. You must move the loading part in separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Well, another silution again:

On begin load simply hide a `load` button and in place of it (say) show a progress bar. On finish of loading or on `stop loading` click make `load` button visible again. In this case you avoid "chain clicks" management you complains about.

Or manage **one** button. First it is `load`, on click, instead, becomes `stop load`. Solution like this you would find often in mobile environment, considering the limited screen space. But I think it can be applied to desktop with great sucess too. Why not?